# Are function spaces Baire?

Tags: general-topology, baire-category

Let $X$ and $Y$ be manifolds and suppose that $X$ is a compact, complete metric space and $Y$ is a complete metric space.
So, both $X$ and $Y$ are Baire spaces.

> **Question:** For what values of $k\geq 0$ is the space $C^k(X,Y)$ (with the $C^k$-topology) a Baire space?

For $k=0$, the space $C^0(X,Y)$ is a Baire space because it is a complete metric space with respect to the uniform metric (since $Y$ is complete).

What about the case $k=\infty$?

References are also very much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is: yes, they are Baire spaces for all $k$, including $k = \infty$.

As long as $X$ is compact, there is essentially no choice about the "correct" topology on $C^k(X,Y)$ and the $C^0$ case elegantly implies the $C^k$-case using the device of [$k$-jet bundles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_bundle) $J^k(X,Y)$. These yield a natural identification of $C^k(X,Y)$ with a closed subspace of $C^0(X,J^k(X,Y))$ (also for $k = \infty$).

If we drop compactness of $X$ (but assume that $X$ is finite-dimensional, hence locally compact), the same technique works, but now there are two distinct reasonable topologies on $C^r(X,Y)$, the weak and strong [Whitney topologies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_topologies). Those still have the Baire property (the strong topology is usually not metrizable).

A solid reference with full details is Hirsch, Differential Topology, chapter 2, especially section 4. See in particular Theorem 4.4 and the paragraphs following it.

Comment: ...and proving $J^k(X,Y)$ complete is easier than the original question?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and the precise reference! I'll have to think about it for a while.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer! I am a bit unsure about the point @GEdgar raised. Hirsch doesn't seem to explain why/if $J^r(X,Y)$ is complete metric (I apologize in case I'm mistaken). An explanation or reference of why $J^r(X,Y)$ is complete metric would be greatly appreciated.
Another thing I'm curious about is the following. What happens if the target $Y$ is an _infinite_ dimensional Fréchet manifold? Is $C^r(X,Y)$ still Baire for $0\leq r\leq \infty$?

Comment: @DaveHartman: If $X$ and $Y$ are finite-dimensional, $J^r(X,Y)$ is a finite-dimensional manifold, hence locally compact second countable and completely metrizable.

Comment: @Martin: Just to make sure I understand your comment correctly: You are saying that every finite dimensional manifold is second countable and completely metrizable? If so, I would really appreciate if you could explain why this is true (or point me to a reference).

Comment: @Dave The definition of a manifold usually includes second countability. The charts for $J^r(X,Y)$ are built from charts of $X$ and $Y$ (or symmetric products thereof) and from this you see that if $X$ and $Y$ are second countable then so is $J^r(X,Y)$. // A manifold is completely metrizable: 1) note that a locally compact second countable space is completely metrizable (use that it's open in its one-point compactification & complete metrizability passes to open subspaces). Or 2) use Whitney's embedding theorem which says that it is homeomorphic to a closed submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^N$.

Comment: @Martin: Thanks a lot for the explanation!