# Is $C^k(X,Y)$ a Lindelöf space?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a compact, finite dimensional smooth manifold and $k\in \mathbb{N}$. Consider the following two cases:

1. $Y$ is a finite dimensional manifold
2. $Y$ is an infinite dimensional Banach manifold

> **Question:** Is the space $C^k(X,Y)$ a [Lindelöf space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindel%C3%B6f_space) in one or both of these cases?

Thanks for any insights. I also appreciate any references of results that go in this direction.

---

**Edit:** In case one assumes that $Y$ is *second countable*, I've come up with the following approach:

- From a comment of @Martin to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/408509/18726) I gather that the space of $k$-jets $J^k(X,Y)$ is *second countable* if $X$ and $Y$ are second countable.
- A result (on page 2) in [this paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1969-022-03/S0002-9939-1969-0267521-9/S0002-9939-1969-0267521-9.pdf) implies that if $X$ and $Z$ are second countable, then $C^0(X,Z)$ (endowed with the compact-open topology) is *separable*.

Setting $Z:=J^r(X,Y)$ and using the fact that the $C^k$-topology on $C^k(X,Y)$ is induced by the $k$-jet extension
$$j^k:C^k(X,Y)\to C^0(X,J^k(X,Y))$$
we can deduce that $C^k(X,Y)$ is *separable*.
A metric space is separable if and only if it's Lindelöf.
Since $C^k(X,Y)$ is a metric space we conclude that it is *Lindelöf*.

Does this approach work, or are there some problems that I'm overlooking?

If it does, some more details of the individual steps (especially why $J^k(X,Y)$ is second countable if $X$ and $Y$ are second countable) are also appreciated.

Thank you for any feedback.

Comment: By your previous question you already know that the answer in case 1 is yes, as $C^k(X,Y)$ is a separable, completely metrizable space.

Comment: @Martin: Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

I found this reference:http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1987-101-03/S0002-9939-1987-0908666-8/S0002-9939-1987-0908666-8.pdf

It shows that in the case that the image is compact (with some other conditions), then the set of continuous functions under pointwise convergence is Lindelof, so its a step in the right direction.

Also this one:http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/1994491?uid=3739864&uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&uid=3739256&sid=21102288886361 discusses several cases, including a Hilbert space as an image.

Comment: Thank you for the references!